# How can I add a timer to get GPS location?

Tags: android, gps, location

I am a beginner, and I have 2 question :-

1. I with below code get gps location now want add a timer to code for any 10 Min get gps and save file GPS.json
2. How can share file gps.json for use in other class this project ?

My code don't problem i tested and for save string used Json format.

Please help me

> MyLocationListener class

```
    private class myLocationListener implements LocationListener{

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(location!=null){
            locManager.removeUpdates(locListener);

            String longitude = "Longitude: " +location.getLongitude();
            String latitude = "Latitude: " +location.getLatitude();
            String altitiude = "Altitiude: " + location.getAltitude();
            String ACRY ="ACR:" + location.getAccuracy();




            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
                JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();


                JSONObject record = new JSONObject();

                record.put("longitude", longitude);
                record.put("latitude", latitude);
                record.put("altitiude", altitiude);
                record.put("ACRY", ACRY);

                jsonArray.put(record);
                jsonObject.put("location", jsonArray);

                File root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Android/test/data");
                File gpxfile = new File(root((" Gps.json")));
                FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(gpxfile);
                byte[] in = (jsonArray.toString().getBytes() );
                fileOutputStream.write(in);
                fileOutputStream.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(context,e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }



    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I prvoide some you can change according your needs.

```
    public void turnGPSOn() {

        String provider = Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(),
                Settings.Secure.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED);
        if (!provider.contains("gps")) {
            final Intent poke = new Intent();
            poke.setClassName("com.android.settings",
                    "com.android.settings.widget.SettingsAppWidgetProvider");
            poke.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_ALTERNATIVE);
            poke.setData(Uri.parse("3"));
            sendBroadcast(poke);
        }
    }


private class MyTimerTask extends TimerTask {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // code to get and send location information
                    locManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
                    if (!locManager
                            .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
                        turnGPSOn();
                    }

                    try {
                        locManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                                LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000, 10,
                                locationListener);

                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                        turnGPSOff();
                    }

                }

            });
        }
    }

    private void updateWithNewLocation(Location location) {
        String latLongString = "";
        try {
            if (location != null) {

                Log.e("test", "gps is on send");
                latitude = Double.toString(location.getLatitude());
                longitude = Double.toString(location.getLongitude());

                Log.e("test", "location send");

                locManager.removeUpdates(locationListener);


                latLongString = "Lat:" + latitude + "\nLong:" + longitude;
                Log.w("CurrentLocLatLong", latLongString);
            } else {
                latLongString = "No location found";
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }

    }

    private final LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            updateWithNewLocation(location);
        }

        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            updateWithNewLocation(null);
        }

        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        }

        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        }
    };

Calling the timer :

long gpsTimeInterval=2000;
void startTimer()
{

myTimer = new Timer();
                                myTimerTask = new MyTimerTask();
                                myTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(myTimerTask, 0,
                                        gpsTimeInterval);
}
```

and i hope you add internet permission into android manifest file.